# How to check if Federation is enabled

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

I want to know what the command is that I can run in the shell to find out if Federation is enabled on a MySQL server or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Login to mysql server and do `SHOW ENGINES\G`, this it what it says on one of my mysql servers:

```
*************************** 10. row ***************************
 Engine: FEDERATED
Support: NO
Comment: Federated MySQL storage engine
```

Comment: COMMAND TO ACTIVATE IT..PLEASE

Comment: You cannot activate it with a simple command. You need to reinstall the mysql server and have a specific version that allows `federated` and please don't ever shout at me again.

Comment: apologies, wasn't shouting didn't realize my upper case was on

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file /etc/mysql/my.cn
At the [mysqld] section add:

[mysqld]
federated

Restart MySql Server and it's done!

Comment: The question is how to check if it's enabled, not how to enable it.

Comment: the question is wrong formatted. if look at the first comment after the first answer you will see that the user asks for how to activated FEDERATED tables.

Comment: @user2766218 Followup questions asked in comments don't really count - comments should only clarify what the original question is asking, not add new questions.  This answer doesn't answer or even help with the original question, so it's inappropriate.